# How to show tree lines in second column in a TreeTable

Tags: java, swing, treetable, jide

I am using TreeTable (com.jidesoft.grid, see [TreeTable](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/grid/TreeTable.html)) to display hierarchical data, which uses a special cell renderer on the first column to paint +/- icon as well as tree line. So, a typical View appears as following:

```
|   Column1  | Column2      |
-----------------------------
|+Item1      | Item4        |
| -Item2     | Item5        |
|   item3    | item6        |
```

While I want the following view for my TreeTable, with +/- buttons and tree lines in second column:

```
|   Column1 | Column2       |
-----------------------------
|Item1      | +Item4        |
|Item2      |  -Item5       |
|item3      |    item6      |
```

I have seen an example and know this is possible, but don't know how to implement this. Any suggestions?

Comment: maybe [@jidesoft](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1029967/jidesoft) will look at your question, maybe you have to ask this question on [JIDE Software Developer Forums](http://www.jidesoft.com/forum/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [TreeTable.setExpandableColumn](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/grid/TreeTable.html#setExpandableColumn%28int%29) method.