# How to the expandable column in second column in TreeViewer

Tags: java, swt, jface

Similar to this question [How to show tree lines in second column in a TreeTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9987725/how-to-show-tree-lines-in-second-column-in-a-treetable) but I am looking for the one thats for TreeViewer from SWT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using the SWT `Tree` or `TreeViewer`.

The expand indicator is always to the left of the first column.